# Mathematical method to minimize a multivariable function of higher order

Tags: function, matrix, mathematical-optimization, eigenvalue, minimization

I have a 12by12 matrix whose elements are function(order 1) of 4 variables. If I diagonalize the matrix , then I get 12 different functions(maximum order is 12) as eigen values. In order to get the minimum eigenvalue within a range of the variables(lets say -5 to 5), I have to minimize all the functions and compare the lowest value of each. I am stuck at this point as I can not find any suitable method for minimization.

Initially I have tried using LLAPACK(as it sorts in ascending order if I assign the value of parameters) subroutine sweeping all the points in 4-dimensional grid of variable within the given range but it takes too long time to cover all the points and compare them.

Then I have checked gradient descent(and conjugate gradient) method but these are well designed for quadratic function and as the order increases, the convergence problem arises and minimization becomes impossible.

Probabilistic methods do not work for me as I require the particular minimum point and it may/may not be reached by these methods.

There might be some packages available in different programming laguage or softwares but I need to know the actual procedure of doing this.

So please suggest me any mathematical method or technique that can work.

Comment: What is the order-1 function? There needs to be code here.

Comment: If the matrix is diagonal then the eigenvalues _are_ the matrix's diagonal elements.

Comment: You say "get the minimum eigenvalue", but there isn't one - there are 12. So what are you actually trying to minimize? The sum of all eigenvalues (the matrix trace)?

Comment: @Reinderien I have stated that the elements are functions of order 1. That means the elements are a linear function of parameters(example: 2x, 2x-3y, x+2y+3z ). Yes, there are 12 eigenvalues, and for coordinate value (lets say x=1.2, y= 1.3, z= 1.4 and p =1.1), lets say f1 has the lowest value then it is minimum. But when the coordinates change, some other function(f2, f3 or anyone) can be minimum. If we take the range of parameters as -5 to 5, we get the minimum valued function at different point. I wantthe coordinate at which the value is lowest and corresponding function.

Comment: Then I do not recommend gradient descent or probabilistic (Monte Carlo?) methods. Please provide the 12 functions of 4 variables as a 12x4 matrix. Then a linear programming approach can be demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have a diagonal matrix is kind of irrelevant for the solution. Construct a linear programming problem where you minimize the minimum of 12 function values, each a linear function of four decision variables:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog
from numpy.random import default_rng

rand = default_rng(seed=0)

# Function coefficients for all 12 functions and all 4 variables
functions = rand.integers(low=-2, high=2, size=(12, 4), endpoint=True)

# Decision variables: minimum function value, function variables, function assignments
c = np.zeros(1 + 4 + 12)
c[0] = 1  # Only the minimum function value is minimized
integrality = np.zeros(1 + 4 + 12, dtype=bool)
integrality[-12:] = True  # Function assignments are binary

bounds = np.empty((1 + 4 + 12, 2))
bounds[0, :] = -np.inf, np.inf  # Minimum function value is unbounded
bounds[1:5, :] = -5, 5          # Function variables are bounded
bounds[-12:, :] = 0, 1          # Assignments are binary

# Exactly one function must be selected as the minimum
A_eq = np.block([
    [0, np.zeros(4), np.ones(12)],
])

# Big-M for last constraint > the biggest magnitude of f
buffer = 2 * (np.abs(functions) @ np.full(shape=4, fill_value=5)).max()

A_ub = np.block([
    # For each function, it must be >= the minimum m. xf >= m  ->  m - xf <= 0
    [np.ones((12, 1)), -functions, np.zeros((12, 12))],
    # For each function, if it is selected, it must also be <= m.
    # xf <= m + buffer(1-s)  ->  -m + xf + buffer*s <= buffer
    [-np.ones((12, 1)), functions, buffer*np.eye(12)],
])
b_ub = np.zeros(12 + 12)
b_ub[-12:] = buffer

result = linprog(
    c=c, integrality=integrality, bounds=bounds,
    A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=[1],
    A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub,
)
assert result.success, result.message
m = result.x[0]
x = result.x[1:5]
assigns = result.x[-12:]

print(f'Minimum function i={(assigns > 0.5).nonzero()[0][0]} at value {m}')
print('x =', x)
print('Function values:')
print(functions @ x)
```

```
Minimum function i=2 at value -35.000000000000014
x = [ 5. -5. -5. -5.]
Function values:
[ 10.  25. -35. -20.  -5. -10.  -5.   0. -10.  -5.  30. -20.]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you have a matrix valued function of some domain, and want to optimize the lowest eigenvalue of that matrix over that domain. That is actually not easily solvable by using a linear program as @Reinderien suggested. Moreover, your problem is nonlinear but its objective does not have continuous second derivatives.

In a hurry you could try [`COBYLA`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-cobyla.html), which is available through `scipy.optimize`.

You should also check that all eigenvalues of your matrices are real, or reformulate the problem if they are not.